# Self-Restarting application crashes under certain circumstances

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I use the [RestartAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15184/How-To-Create-a-Self-Restartable-Application) to restart my application if I need to reload it. It works fine until I launch any Windows dialog (e.g. Open Dialogue), which ends with Open button being clicked! In this case, if I later choose to restart the new application (after restarting) will not be able to open ANY files. If I click Cancel button the new restarted application will work just fine.

It took me a long time to figure out that the difference between the two restarts is the Open button with some Open Dialog that is completely unrelated to the application restart. Note that I have eliminated the code that gets executed after the Open button is clicked so there's no way that it could be caused by some memory corrupting code that the Open button just initiates.

It is enough to click the Open button once (so I may 5 times click Cancel than once Open and than for example 3 times Cancel) and any attempt to restart the application however "late" will result in the new instance not being able to open any files (not even with `std::ifstream`).

Some details:

- Visual Studio 2010
- Windows 7 x64 (but with 32bit XP it is the same)
- the dialog is launched in a separate thread
- I use Allegro 5.0 for graphics but that should not be related
- The dialog is launched by GetOpenFileName function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about RestartAPI, but you can create temporary batch file which will restart the process without any problems.

Comment: Seems hard to believe that they would introduce an apparently complex API for something you can accomplish trivially with a batch file.

Comment: There are injects only, which is not safe.

Comment: Can you post some link or something? Anyway I know there's a way to register your process for restart since Vista, but my code has to work with Windows XP as well... And what do you mean by "There are injects only, which is not safe." ?

Comment: You have to inject some assembly code into some random process, which will do that work for you, so called a "shell code" which also will flag some AVs for doing that.

Comment: I do not understand that any better. Can you please post some link or something where I can read more about that? Also when you write "There are injects only, which is not safe." I don't know whether you mean "There" as in RestartAPI or "There" as in the kind of batch file You suggest.

Comment: Do you mean creating a new process with CreateProcess that will run batchfile with something like: taskkill myApp.exe & myApp.exe?

Comment: If you don't believe me, Adobe Flash Player Installer uses batch file to delete self in temp directory. More about it, you can create new batch file, which kills your process and starts again. "Injects" are low-level stuff, you'll have to understand a lot, but in this case just search how to start and stop process with batch file. EDIT: taskkill is not an option, because process with same name can be also running, use PID instead. You should create batch file at run-time. Good luck!

Comment: How come that taskkill is not an option? Well i can use taskkill /PID. Or is there something that eludes me? What other command would you use then? //EDIT: also I need to wait till the previous instance finishes. Normally I would use start /wait but the process is already running!